# Вызов перегруженного метода

Tags: java

Прошу помочь. Почему в данном случае вызывается метод с аргументом String?

```
class TestClass {
public static void method(Object o){
    System.out.println("In Object");
}
public static void method(String s){
    System.out.println("In String");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    method(null);
}
}
```

А здесь же например вообще ошибка компиляции происходит.

```
class TestClass {
public static void method(Integer o){
    System.out.println("In Integer");
}
public static void method(StringBuilder s){
    System.out.println("In StringBuilder");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    method(null);
}
}
```

Почему в первом случае компиляцию проходит и выполняется метод с аргументом String, а в другом случае ошибка компиляции при вызове с параметром null?

Comment: Спрашиваете про ошибку, но не приводите текст ошибки

Comment: Что документация говорит по вашему вопросу?

Comment: Будет вызван более КОНКРЕТНЫЙ метод.
Но я так и не понял, почему во втором случае идет ошибка:
java: reference to method is ambiguous
  both method method(java.lang.Integer) in TestClass and method method(java.lang.StringBuilder) in TestClass match

Comment: Выдвину предположение: в первом случае String яаляется наследником Object, то есть String будет более конкретным вариантом. Все, чем может являться String будет проходить через String метод, всё остальное будет прозодить через Object. Во втором случае ни один их методов не является более конкретным относительно другого, нет никакой прямой связи в наследовании между StringBuilder  и Integer и любой из них может принимать null, а значит компилятор не можнет однозначно решить, какой метод вызвать для null - от того и ошибка компиляции.

Answer (score 2):

Java всегда будет пытаться использовать наиболее конкретную версию метода.
В первом случае не возникает ошибки, так как `Object` является суперклассом класса `String`, а следовательно метод принимающий `String` является более конкретной версией, и java может определить какой из методов использовать.
В втором же случае, `Integer` и `StringBuilder` более конкретны чем `Object` однако не более конкретны чем каждый из них, так как оба объекта наследуются от `Object`, и java не может определить какому из методов передать `null`. В данном случае вам нужно явно привести тип

```
method((Integer)null);
```

Подробнее можете почитать на сайте оракла https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5